# Data set for named entity recognition

Tags: nlp, dataset, training-data, named-entity-recognition

I have to create training data set for named-entity recognition project.

For example, I have text

```
"Last year, I was in London where I saw Tom"
```

Training data should be

```
"Last year, I was in <ENAMEX TYPE="LOCATION">London</ENAMEX> where I saw  
<ENAMEX TYPE="NAME">Tom</ENAMEX>"
```

It is easy to do it by hand but it takes time when there are a large number of data.  I can not use an open set. I have small training data set but I should extend it.

How can I create a larger training data set by extending small training data set? Are there some ready packages or open projects for it? Or do you suggest different methods?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you aren't already, use a tool like [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/) to make annotating go faster.

Since it looks like you're marking tokens that are only ever used in one way, you can make a list of them and auto-annotate them. For example, `London` is always a place you so you can replace all instances of `London` with `<ENAMEX TYPE="LOCATION">London</ENAMEX>`. Be careful of cases where this doesn't work, like Turkey or China (`We ate turkey sandwiches off china plates.`).

There's a project called [Prodigy](https://prodi.gy/) in beta that's designed for getting models off the ground, though I haven't had a chance to try it yet it should be worth a look.